# Attempting to upload to my PPA: the signature could not be verified

Tags: ppa, eclipse, packaging

I've created a PPA (https://launchpad.net/~brentonhorne/+archive/ubuntu/eclipse-ide-cpp) that is presently completely empty but I have been trying to upload my `.changes` file to it (with `dput eclipse-ide-cpp eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0-1_amd64.changes`), but everytime I do I get the error message:

```
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: the signature could not be verified.
Please remember that the signature file (.sig or .asc)
should be the first file given on the command line.
No signature on /home/fusion809/GitHub/mine/eclipse-ide-cpp/eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0-1_amd64.changes.
```

FYI I have created this `~/.dput.cf` file (via following the instructions at https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading):

```
[eclipse-ide-cpp]
fqdn = ppa.launchpad.net
method = ftp
incoming = ~brentonhorne/ubuntu/eclipse-ide-cpp/
login = anonymous
allow_unsigned_uploads = 0
```

Now, I tried to create a `.sig` file for my changes file with:

```
gpg --output eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0-1_amd64.changes.sig --sign eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0-1_amd64.changes
```

But even after doing this whenever I try to upload my changes file with `dput` I get same error message I previously reported. Now if I run `dput eclipse-ide-cpp eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0-1.changes.sig` instead (as that is what I thought my original upload error message indicated I should be doing) I get the error message:

```
Not a .changes file.
Please select a .changes file to upload.
Tried to upload: eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0-1.changes.sig
```

My changes files were generated by cd'ing into the `eclipse-ide-cpp_4.6.0` subdirectory of [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/fusion809/eclipse-ide-cpp) of mine and running:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

in case you're wondering if I made a mistake when I was creating my `.changes` files.

Answer (score 0):

You seem get some advance in packaging, I'm learning too.

> ```
> dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
> ```

From `man dpkg-buildpackage`

```
-us    Do not sign the source package.
-uc    Do not sign the .changes file.
```

:) you order it not to sign them. Remove both options then try again.

Side notes:

- You should sync your GPG key with `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371` using `seahorse` or other tools. Otherwise launchpad will reject your packages.
- Calling simply `dpkg-buildpackage` with generate both the source + binary(your machine arch only) packages. If you are confident that binary is building fine, you can make the process shorter by building only source package and let launchpad build all the binaries, using:

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -S
  ```

  From `man dpkg-buildpackage`

  > ```
  >   -S     Specifies a source-only build, no binary packages need to 
  >          be made.  Passed to dpkg-genchanges.  Note: if what you 
  >          want is  simply  to (re-)build the source package, using 
  >          dpkg-source is always better as it does not require any 
  >          build dependencies to be installed to be able to call the 
  >          clean target.
  > ```

  Also `dpkg-source` another option that don't need to installed build dependencies to build source package.